# How do you keep the original order in an ArrayList for unique values?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

For example if i want to preserve the order of the string that appear first, but I also want the second occurrence of the duplicate to follow after the first one on the list of output. for example if I added:
    arrlist.add("bob");
    arrlist.add("pat");
    arrlist.add("tan");
    arrlist.add("bob");
    arrlist.add("mat");
    arrlist.add("cat");
    arrlist.add("dog");
    arrlist.add("cat");

I want the output to be

```
String = bob
String = bob
String = pat
String = tan
String = mat
String = cat
String = cat
String = dog
```

This is my code:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create an empty array list with an initial capacity
        ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        // use add() method to add elements in the list
        arrlist.add("bob");
        arrlist.add("pat");
        arrlist.add("tan");
        arrlist.add("bob");
        arrlist.add("mat");
        arrlist.add("cat");
        arrlist.add("dog");
        arrlist.add("cat");

        // let us print all the elements available in list
        for (String number : arrlist) {
            System.out.println("String = " + number);
        } 

        // retrieves element at 4th postion
        String retval=arrlist.get(3);
        System.out.println("Retrieved element is = " + retval); 


    }
}
```

Comment: Your English seems to be coming along quite nicely! Do you mean that you want the items to print out in sorted order?

Comment: yeah I do but for example if I had Added The string 1)apple 2) banana 3)apple 4) mango instead of outputting the same order I want the duplicate to follow the first occurrence of it duplicate so i want it to ouput: apple,apple, banana, mango

Comment: just to get this straight: if I added {apple, banana, apple, mango} you would want the list print off:
apple, apple, banana, mango

Or, it could be that you want the same elements to appear next to each other.  if I added {apple, banana, mango, kiwi, banana} you want to print off: apple, banana, banana, mango, kiwi

Comment: yes, that's what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the items to come out in sorted order (according to alphabetical order), take a look at a [priority queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Every time you add an item, it is added based off of the comparator. The comparator decides the ordering (alphabetical, by length, whatever).

Then, when you print and remove items from the front of the queue, your items will print off in order.

Comment: I don't think they want it alphabetical at all, sounded like "unique insertion order" to me.  `bob bob pat tan mat cat cat dog`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index of a value in the list with indexOf(yourString). You can use that to check if the entry exists and insert the value after that one.
See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more information.

Something along the lines of

```
if(arrlist.indexOf(myString) == -1) // Not found
   arrlist.add(myString)
else
   arrlist.add(arrlist.indexOf(myString), myString)
```

Well there I did it, wrote you the code...shame on me.

Comment: I tried implementing this, but it doesn't recognize the variable myString

Answer (score 2):

That's not really "preserving", because in a raw sense, you really did input `bob` **first** and **fourth**, not **first** and **second**.

There are no native datasets that I'm aware of that accomplish this, however, you can achieve this with a `LinkedHashMap` (preserves the order of the first time a key was entered) where the value is the count of the number of times the item was added:

- Create an `add` method that gets the value from the hash map or defaults to 0.  Increment it.  Put it on the hash map again.
- When reading the list, iterate over the map entry set and then output the key once for the number in value.

**Example**

```
public static class ReorderingList {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> items =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    public void add(String item) {
        Integer value = items.get(item);
        if (value == null) value = 0;
        value++;
        items.put(item, value);
    }

    public List<String> asList() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : items.entrySet()) {
            for (int i=0; i < entry.getValue(); i++) {
                result.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReorderingList rlist = new ReorderingList();

    rlist.add("bob");
    rlist.add("pat");
    rlist.add("tan");
    rlist.add("bob");
    rlist.add("mat");
    rlist.add("cat");
    rlist.add("dog");
    rlist.add("cat");

    List<String> arrlist = rlist.asList();

    // let us print all the elements available in list
    for (String number : arrlist) {
        System.out.println("String = " + number);
    } 

    // retrieves element at 4th postion
    String retval=arrlist.get(3);
    System.out.println("Retrieved element is = " + retval); 
}
```

Test output:

```
String = bob
String = bob
String = pat
String = tan
String = mat
String = cat
String = cat
String = dog
Retrieved element is = tan
```

### [Working ideone example](http://ideone.com/mMmx4H)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Guava, you could consider using a [LinkedHashMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html), which will directly solve your problem without needing to adapt it to e.g. the LinkedHashMap as proposed by NickC.

Comment: Does this actually solve the problem? The [javadoc](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html#elementSet%28%29) for LinkedHashMultiset suggests that iteration order over unique elements using either elementSet() or entrySet() methods is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Collections.sort(myArrayList);`. You're using an `ArrayList` of `String`, therefore if you want to use some other kind of object, you'll have to implement the `compare()` method inside your object to use the `Collections.sort()`.

Take a look at [Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for a better explanation.